# Iterate through nested List of Objects

Tags: user-interface, jsf

In Primefaces 5.1 (Tomcat 8 and Servlet 3.0) you can iterate through `List<Objects>` using DataGrid, DataList, DataTable etc.. for instance:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
  <p:column headerText="Id">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name="dtBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView implements Serializable {

  private List<Car> cars;

  @ManagedProperty("#{carService}")
  private CarService service;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      cars = service.createCars(10);
  }

  public List<Car> getCars() {
      return cars;
  }

  public void setService(CarService service) {
      this.service = service;
  }
}
```

But say the `Car` object has a property like `washes` so that when I do:

```
<h:outputText value="#{car.washes}" />
```

Inside the dataTable it returns a list of `List<Washes>`. I can not select the index so how do I iterate though the `List<Washes>` inside the dataTable?

I know I could create a dataGrid inside the data table and then do the same as with the cars to iterate through the list of Washes. But this creates a new "HTML table with a border inside one of the cells". How can I just iterate though the list and output the string from washes: `#{washes.foo}`

---

**Update**: I get this error when trying to use `<ui:repeat>` as per the answer:

```
Property 'foo' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet
```

When I use `<p:dataGrid>` instead of `<ui:repeat>` it works.

Also, I was returning a set instead of a list so I had to use toArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just nest another iterating component like as you can nest a `for` loop in plain Java.

Here's an example nesting another `<p:dataTable>`, assuming that `Wash` has a property `foo`:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.cars}" var="car">
  <p:column headerText="Washes">
    <p:dataTable value="#{car.washes}" var="wash">
      <p:column headerText="Foo">#{wash.foo}</p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Use `<ui:repeat>` or perhaps `<h:dataTable>` if you want markupless/styleless iteration:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.cars}" var="car">
  <p:column headerText="Washes">
    <ui:repeat value="#{car.washes}" var="wash">
      #{wash.foo}
    </ui:repeat>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

It's by the way strange to use a plural as class name while you can have multiple of them in a `List`. You might want to rename `Washes` to `Wash`. The above code snippets have already taken this into account. You see that the code becomes more self-documenting this way.

---

**Update** as per your error; the `<ui:repeat>` and `<h:dataTable>` components doesn't support iterating over a `Set<E>`. The support will come in future JSF 2.3 version. If it's not an option to replace `Set<E>` by a `List<E>`, then just get an array out of it as below:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{car.washes.toArray()}" ...>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried ui:repeat and h:dataTable but they will not show #{wash.foo} text when I try p:dataGrid it works. This may be because I am using prime faces. How can I get this to work with prime faces?

Comment: `<h:dataTable>` requires `<h:column>`. `<ui:repeat>` must work usual way. If both still doesn't work, make sure you didn't forgot `xmlns:h` and `xmlns:ui`.

Comment: Hi,I have xmlns:h and xmlns:ui but they don't work inside the <p:dataTable> for prime faces 5.2

Comment: It works for me (and anyone else) when starting off with a blank project with most minimal configuration and most recent versions. Your problem is caused elsewhere. Best is to create a MCVE so you (or we) can quickly spot the problem. Then repost it as a new question as this problem is unrelated to the question currently asked. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the link. I updated the code/question above.

Comment: Right, you got a concrete error. In the future, never overgeneralize errors as "don't work". Good errors namely represent the whole answer at their own. If you can't interpret the error, simply share it with someone who can. See updated answer for a layman's translation of the error you got.

Comment: And, be careful in formulating the question. You said there that you've a `List<Washes>`, but as per the error it's actually a `Set<Washes>`. Try to be less careless in this too. A `Set` is not the same as a `List`.

Comment: Haha! You got it right. Sorry for being so unprofessional on my post. Will work harder on my next ones. Thanks for all the guidance. Really helped. I had to use .toArray() and it works!